# OAuth library source

Tags: qt, oauth, symbian

For an application in symbian we need to use the OAuth. I searched in net but I could not get any one. 
If anyone know about any open source library please let me k now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OAuth is not well suited to rich mobile phone applications because of the requirement to use a browser for authentication. [This research](http://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/UXFedLogin/nobrowser) gives a good overview of the problems.

Unless you are willing to accept the user experience implications in a rich app (dropping into the browser for authentication), or you are building a widget/web-based app, I'd avoid OAuth.

There are no OAuth libraries for Symbian - integration with the browser is not as simple as it should be. However, there are plenty examples of OAuth libraries which shouldn't be too much bother to port to Symbian C++ (for example, [Java example](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/), [OAuth in C](http://liboauth.sourceforge.net/)).